# cordova (phonegap) works different as app and inside phonegap app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a web-app with angularjs. I wanted to turn it into a mobile app (android) using phonegap.

I have used phonegap build: https://build.phonegap.com

And every thing worked fine!

But this process is slow for developing. So I have installed phonegap dev app which automatically loads updates into my mobile app; but in this case mobile app works inside phonegap app on mobile.

And now, my app does not work correctly. The problem is that angularjs `$routeProvider` does not work (it loads the template fine, but it does not load the necessary controller):

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/x', {
            templateUrl: 'static/html/temp/x.html',
            controller: 'XController',
            controllerAs: 'XCtrl',
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'static/html/temp/y.html',
            controller: 'YController',
            controllerAs: 'YCtrl'
        });
```

Please again remind that my app works correctly when I install as independent mobile app; but does not work inside phonegap dev app.

I appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

Somehow it started to load the `YController`. However, it does not execute `ng-init` code which is on base `div` of template:

```
<div ng-init="YCtrl.init()">
....
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using html5mode ? Phonegap has no web server and act like a file storage system. If on your desktop you right click on index.html and open in browser, does your application work ? (so with no server)

Comment: html5mode is set to false. As I said, it works as independent mobile app on android, building with phonegap build. On desktop without server does not work because in that case it gives other errors:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/phonegap_ws/king/Efsane%20King/www/static/html/temp/y.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Wich was the version of phonegap used in your phonegap build project and wich is the version of phonegap or cordova you installed on your computer? Cordova 5 has new security policies that may block some access (don't know about angular). You may have a look at the configuration of the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist.

Comment: @QuickFix thank you, finally I have found the problem. I wrote as answer as reference.

Answer (score 1):

For people who experiences similar problem:

After dedicating one entire day finally I saw the problem:

```
console.log()
```

It works for trivial inputs (ie. texts). However, for complex objects (eg. `console.log($scope)`, **$scope is defined**) somehow it does not work and the worse is phonegap desktop app does not show any error log for this. It clearly seems to be a bug.

So, commenting out `console.log` codes solved the problem.

Comment: Wasn't the issue just that $scope was not declared and so created a syntax error? (some webview may continue on errors and others stop immediatly)

Comment: @QuickFix No. It happens just like I answered. As I said, it works in any other case (independent android app, desktop chrome, etc). So, $scope (or any other complex object that causes to fail phonegap app) is defined.